# Why is faster pc i5:ram 4, ssd 256, core 4, then laptop i7: ram 16, ssd 500, core 10?

Tags: memory, ssd, cpu, performance, python

I have such a case and maybe you can help me, what is the reason?

I did a test, reading an excel file (310 MB) in python (pandas).

Laptop(IdeaPad Slim 5 16IRL8): i7, ram 16, ssd 500, core 10, 2.4 ghz, windows 11,

Work desktop computer: i5, ram 4, ssd 256, core 4, 3 ghz, windows 10.

The laptop reads the excel file in 30 minutes, and the work computer in 10 minutes. The only advantage in ghz is the work computer, and because of that there should be such a big difference even when reading a file? What could be the reason?
when I run code in i7, laptop has not cooler noise.

[i5 CPU-----](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THb0L.png)

[i7 CPU-----](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SukgW.png)

[i7 SSD-----](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5mgU.png)

Comment: Does the i7 have only 1 memory stick? What type of RAM?

Comment: RAM: speed 2500mhz, slots used 2-2, form - row of chips.  What additional information is needed?

Comment: Looking at the CPU graphs your laptop is probably thermally throttling. It is stuck down at 1.8GHz when it should boost up to 4.9GHz.  The i5 is managing 3.45GHz.

Comment: Yes, indeed. The maximum speed is 1.8GHz. what can I do?

Comment: https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000211304-Using-the-High-performance-power-plan-Windows- Choose "high performance" if that does not work check  https://www.reddit.com/r/intel/comments/j1kfu2/i5_stuck_at_18ghz_after_intel_xtu_8250u/

Comment: I can not see "high performance", I see only Balance. but I can add new plan

Comment: Also, see if *reducing* Virtual Memory on the laptop makes it faster. An SSD is still slower than RAM,  so any drive I/O for VM slows the machine. With 16 GB, I'd set VM initial and max size to 8 GB, as an experiment... you can always set it back, if it doesn't help.